# Can an iframe be embedded into the Facebook Newsfeed?

Tags: facebook, iframe

The iframe could contain a HTML5 video, a photo, some text, etc. And will definitely contain Javascript to switch between the different content types.

Can this be embedded into a Facebook Newsfeed using opengraph? So far I it seems you can only embed a HTML5 video or SWF? Is this right?

Comment: No, you can not embed iframes into the newsfeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not embed iframes into the newsfeed.

The only form of “interactive” content that Facebook allow at the moment are flash players as far as i know.

Comment: Ive been asked to find a reference to this in the facebook documentation, and I cant find anything. Sorry to bother you further, but do you have a link that supports this?

Comment: For embedding flash you mean? See the docs for “Feed Gaming” – it’s talking about embedding flash games, but from what I know for playing videos in feed the principle should be the same: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/

Comment: If I share soundcloud URL, they manage to be able to serve iframe to  embed their html5 player without any flash... I wonder how they do that

Comment: @Mustafa: They have a partnership with Facebook, and therefor get special treatment in that regard.